# OpsCenter 5.2.0 - Event log view error: "Undefined name target_node in selection clause"

Tags: opscenter

I've got an upgraded instance from OpsCenter 5.1 to 5.2.  When I try to look at the event log, I receive this error in the UI:

```
Error loading events: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Undefined name target_node in selection clause"
```

And a corresponding line in the opscenter log.

```
ERROR: Problem while calling EventsController (InvalidRequest): code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Undefined name target_node in selection clause
```

"

And ideas why I'm unable to see the event log?

Comment: Hi Shawn, the schema for Opsc was migrated in 5.2, it sounds like something went wrong with the migration.  Did you have any logs from when you first started opsc 5.2?  Also can you post the schema for the events table?  Run something like this: cqlsh> use "OpsCenter";
cqlsh:OpsCenter> describe TABLE events;  you'll get a result that looks something like this https://gist.github.com/philip-doctor/a358ffe460d22bc49eb5  if you can post that it would be super helpful, thanks!

Comment: I think you're right, it didn't run the schema change on that table. There were quite a few columns missing.  I added the ones from your gist and now the error is gone and I can see events.  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yeah sure, you might consider checking the other tables too to make sure that they're on comment='{"info": "OpsCenter management data.", "version": [5, 2, 0]}' otherwise you're cruising for another problem in the future.

Comment: Strangely, the events table had 5, 2, 0 in the comment so I'm not sure that's a good indicator.  Where can I get the schema for 5.2.0 to check the others against?

Comment: Hi Shawn, there's no official doc for this, but I did a describe keyspace on a fresh install of opsc 5.2.0, if you did a migration from 5.1.x and the table didn't change, the comment version might still read 5.1.x (ex: pdp table didn't require migration and hence didn't get an updated version).  https://gist.github.com/philip-doctor/1362a1fdd95adcf73cc9

Comment: Thanks.  All the rest of my tables look good.  I appreciate your help on this.